# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined Ionic/Firestore

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in Firestore/Ionic. I have this problem:
I have the following function that returns the information of a user, saved in a Firestore document:

profile.service.ts:

```
  getProfile(id: string) {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(id);
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      return doc.data();
    });
  }
```

If I want to show this information on my profile.page.ts page, it tells me that, for example, username is undefined.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.profile = this.profileService.getProfile(this.id);
  }
```

The problem is that they are asynchronous calls, but I don't know how to modify the code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: make `ngOnInit` `async` and add `await` before `this.profileService.getProfile(this.id)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but doesn't work. I have resolved using :     ngOnInit() {
        this.profileService.getProfile(this.id).subscribe((data)=>{ this.profile=data;
        });
    }

Comment: You'll also need to place a `return` before `docRef.get()...`.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution provided in the comments by @ChrisCv and @FrankvanPuffelen as a Community wiki for better visibility.

The error has been solved by using the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getProfile(this.id).subscribe((data) => { this.profile=data; });
    }
```

You'll also need to place a `return` before `docRef.get()...`.